# How do I output python3 target code with antlr.jar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I downloaded:

```
antlr-4.7-complete.jar
```

to `C:\ANTLR\` and renamed to `C:\ANTLR\antlr.jar`.

I also did:
`pip3 install antlr4-python3-runtime`.

Which I assume is meant for coding with since the download docs [here](http://www.antlr.org/download.html), say:

> All users should download the ANTLR tool itself and then choose a runtime target below, unless you are using Java which is built into the tool jar.

So it looks like I have all the tools required.  But doing:

`cd C:\ANTLR` 
`java -jar antlr.jar arithmetic.g4`

Outputs Java code!

How do I make it output or convert the output to, Python3 code?

Thanks.

Please don't tell me this isn't a programming question.  There is no other place that would give an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K, answered my own question:

From [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/python-target.md):

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 MyGrammar.g4
```

So I guess I do something like:

```
java -jar antlr.jar -Dlanguage=Python3 arithmetic.g4
```

Comment: That worked. Next step is to get a `helloworld.py` example to run.